# Any way to download and view the war that's deployed on heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Is there any way we can download the war which got deployed in heroku?

We committed and pushed the code using maven and git commands of heroku.

I know there is clone command, which actually download the source code which got updated, but I want to download exact war which got deployed.

Comment: How is your war created and is stored in git?

Comment: War created using maven command and yes stored in git.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its a bad practice to store binaries in git.
Use something like: [GItHub LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

If your file is in git you can simply fetch the code to your machine and checkout the folder/file you need

```
git fetch --all --prune
git checkout HEAD <path>
```

You can also clone **only** the latest commit of the project without the whole history and again checkout the war that you want. This will save you to clone the full project.

```
git clone --depth 1 <url>
```